# Words frequency with number of letters (basic loop only)

Tags: c, loops, frequency

I Want to write C program to print words length and their frequency by letters number with basic loops techniques. I could get the word length work but I stuck with frequency
(example: Do 2 not 3 judge 5 a 1 book 4 (had solved this))

- there are # words with 1 letter
- there are # words with 2 letter

etc...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

char word[30];
int i = 0,b=0,c=0,j=0,d=0;
printf("Please enter a word: ");

for (i = 0; i < 30 ; i++){
    scanf("%s", word);           
          while (word[b]!='\0'){ 
              b++;  
          }   
    printf("%s %d ", word, b);
    b = 0;
}

return 0;  
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for with the frequency part, could you provide an example?

Comment: there are 1 words with 1 letter // a
there are 1 words with 2 letter // do
there are 1 words with 3 letter // not

Comment: `int count[MAX_WORD_LENGTH] = {0};` then your code, just add `count[b]++;` immediately after the `printf()` call inside the loop; and, finally, print the contents of this new array.

Comment: but I want it just with basic loop without any function or algorithm

Comment: this is the solution that I cannot understand https://i.postimg.cc/SNqxfy3y/1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question wasn't completely clear. But from what I understood, you also wanted to print the number of times(**frequency**) a word of length '*l*' is inputted by the user. So I will answer that :

You could just **store the length of the word** in an array that the user inputs. Once all the inputs are read, you can just print the frequency of each word length from the stored array

Refer the following code to understand what I meant :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

char word[30];
int i = 0,b=0,c=0,j=0,d=0;
int word_length_freq[30]={0};       //an array which will store the frequency of word length(all initialized to 0)
                                   //eg. if word is "hello" it will increase count of word_length_freq[5] by 1
printf("Please enter a word: ");

for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
    scanf("%s", word);           
          while (word[b]!='\0'){ 
              b++;  
          }   
    word_length_freq[b]++;
    printf("%s %d ", word, b);    
    b = 0;
}

for(int i=1;i<30;i++){          //This will print the frequency of all words from length 1 to 30
    printf("There are %d words of length %d\n",word_length_freq[i],i);
}

return 0;  
}
```

I hope this solves your question !

Comment: this is the solution that I cannot understand https://i.postimg.cc/SNqxfy3y/1.png

Comment: @Florian what's your doubt in that?

Comment: not doubt just I could not understand it so I searched for simpler solution, your seems more easy to understand at least for me so thanks

Comment: Thanks. Just to add, In both the solution, the array which stores frequency is incremented by 1 after reading every word, the **index** which is incremented being the length of word. I have also left an example in my solution.